# Error : Finished standard no-slot{} default handler [ns-2]

Tags: networking, simulation, simulator, ns2

I have a problem with ns-2 simulation... When i run my simulation it gives me this Error :

```
--- Classfier::no-slot{} default handler (tcl/lib/ns-lib.tcl) ---
    _o52: no target for slot -1
    _o52 type: Classifier/Port
content dump:
classifier _o52
    0 offset
    0 shift
    2147483647 mask
    2 slots
        slot 0: _o67 (CMUTrace/Recv)
        slot 255: _o54 (CMUTrace/Recv)
---------- Finished standard no-slot{} default handler ----------
```

I tried to find a solution in internet but no one have answered this question before.
Do anyone know what is this Error for?

Here is my code :

```
set val(chan)           Channel/WirelessChannel    ;# Channel Type
set val(prop)           Propagation/TwoRayGround   ;# radio-propagation model
set val(netif)          Phy/WirelessPhy            ;# network interface type
set val(mac)            Mac/802_11         ;# mac type
set val(ifq)            Queue/DropTail/PriQueue    ;# interface queue type
set val(ll)             LL                         ;# link layer type
set val(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna        ;# antenna model
set val(ifqlen)         50                         ;# max packet in ifq
set val(nn)             4                         ;# number of mobilenodes
set val(rp)             AODV                       ;# routing protocol
set val(x)      250
set val(y)      250

set ns_ [new Simulator]

set tracefile [open W.tr w]
$ns_ trace-all $tracefile

set namfile [open N.nam w]
$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namfile $val(x) $val(y)

set topo [new Topography]
$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)

set god_ [create-god $val(nn)]

set chan_ [new $val(chan)]

$ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
     -llType $val(ll) \
     -macType $val(mac) \
     -ifqType $val(ifq) \
     -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
     -antType $val(ant) \
     -propType $val(prop) \
     -phyType $val(netif) \
     -topoInstance $topo \
     -agentTrace ON \
     -routerTrace ON \
     -macTrace ON \
     -movementTrace ON \
     -channel $chan_

     for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} {incr i} {
         set node($i) [$ns_ node]
         $node($i) random-motion 0
         set xx_ [expr rand()*200]
         set yy_ [expr rand()*200]
         #$ns_ at 0.0 "$node($i) setdest $xx_ $yy_ 0.0"
         puts "xx_ $xx_"
         puts "yy_ $yy_"
         $node($i) set X_ $xx_
         $node($i) set Y_ $yy_
         $node($i) set Z_ 0.0
         $ns_ initial_node_pos $node($i) 10
     }

for {set i 0} {$i < [expr $val(nn) / 2]} {incr i} {
set tcp($i) [new Agent/TCP]
set udp($i) [new Agent/UDP]
set cbr($i) [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
set ftp($i) [new Application/FTP]
set null($i) [new Agent/Null]
set tcpsink($i) [new Agent/TCPSink]
}

$ns_ attach-agent $node(0) $tcp(0)
$ns_ attach-agent $node(1) $tcpsink(0)
$ftp(0) attach-agent $tcp(0)
$ns_ connect $tcp(0) $tcpsink(0)

proc stop {} {
 global ns_ namfile tracefile
 $ns_ flush-trace
 close $namfile
 close $tracefile
 exec nam N.nam
 exit 0
}

for {set i 0} {$i < 1} {incr i} {
$ns_ at $i "$ftp([expr $i / 2]) start"
$ns_ at 20.0 "$ftp([expr $i / 2]) stop"
$ns_ at 25.0 "puts \"NS EXITING...\""
$ns_ at 25.0 "stop"
}

puts "Starting simulation..."
$ns_ run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://ns2ultimate.tumblr.com/post/520626807/classifier-no-slot-error
- http://mailman.isi.edu/pipermail/ns-users/2010-August/068657.html
- https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=Classfier::no-slot{}+default+handler

---

» Classfier::no-slot{}+default+handler (tcl/lib/ns-lib.tcl) « can have several causes:

Wrong OS, an error in your tcl code, (wrong ns2 version ?), etc. etc.

---

Some more information is required, if you want a solution:

- OS Name / version / architecture, like Fedora 22 - i686, Ubuntu 14.04 - i686.
- The ns2 version. The name of the simulation.tcl. The used protocol.
- And if the script.tcl is a new one, please show the code, or upload the file.

Comment: OS : ubuntu, VERSION :14.04 , NS-2 : 2-35 , PROTOCOL : AODV ...................... Its a simple simulation just to begin and then editing it... I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

@Jenova, You may have a wrecked build of ns-2.35 ? Did you change some code in ns-2.35 ? Like adding a patch with an extra protocol ?

The suggested ns-2.35 version is :  ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

I.e. the 'Nov 2014 update' : Can use all gcc/g++ versions 4.4.x .. 5.2.0

---

Your code : I get the same OK output → With any OS, any architecture (i686 or x86_64), any ns2 version, any added (harmless) protocol to that ns2 : Example OS´s, used to test your above file.tcl → →
PCLinuxOS 2015 - i686, Ubuntu 12.04 - i686, Ubuntu 12.04 - x86_64, **Ubuntu 14.04 - x86_64 , Ubuntu 14.04 - i686**.

```
$ ns AODV-Jenova.tcl

num_nodes is set 4
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
xx_ 74.759948474708921
yy_ 90.454014432827947
xx_ 60.620572539335384
yy_ 49.962668609788018
xx_ 122.57132470727494
yy_ 56.254355169951154
xx_ 66.947341368974804
yy_ 183.96638835965021
Starting simulation...
channel.cc:sendUp - Calc highestAntennaZ_ and distCST_
highestAntennaZ_ = 1.5,  distCST_ = 550.0
SORTING LISTS ...DONE!
NS EXITING...
```

.. and 'nam' opens a nice animation.

---

... We still don't know which Ubuntu 14.04 you have. Please show the reply from

```
$ uname -m
```

Comment: Its : Ubuntu 14.4 i686

Comment: Well now that i checked the script works fine until i just add this line in aodv.cc :       tcl.evalf("$ns_ at 0.0 \"$node(0) color MediumBlue\"");

Answer (score 0):

Ref. your comment: »» tcl.evalf("$ns_ at 0.0 \"$node(0) color MediumBlue\""); ««

Is tcl code, I think. And cannot be added to a c++ file, AFAIK.

See https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=tcl.evalf("%24ns_+at+0.0+\"%24node(0)+color+MediumBlue\"")%3B+

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](http://mailman.isi.edu/pipermail/ns-users/2010-August/068657.html).
It's most likely that you are asking NS2 to send a packet to a non-existing
object. You might wanna check if you properly attached source and destination nodes before you start sending packets